# Display only the Time in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new here, I'm stuck in converting an array of strings with values of "1024" and "2255" to Time value.

I need to convert the strings to times with format: "10:24 AM". How will I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that array store value of Time in long value, you can try to add value of current day in long with this value and convert back into Date, and then use Date.ToString() to show the format you desired.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (off my mind):

```
var myString = "2255";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myString,"HHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var convertedString = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

`convertedString` should have "10:25 PM"

Comment: I would change `dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt");` to `dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));` to ensure that AM/PM works.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: agreed, but I'd use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in that case. `Invariant` uses AM and PM too.